# Job management for Linux and numerical simulations

Tags: linux, ssh, software-rec

I am working on numerical simulations, and I run them with parameters so that they finish in a couple minutes. I'd like to let them run longer, maybe days.

Currently, I have the parameters compiled into the C programs, but I guess I should make all the parameters command line arguments, so that I can change them on startup.

However, I am not sure how to distribute “tasks” onto several Linux computers. They have multiple cores each, but I may not be able to install extra software, since they are university computers that allow SSH, but no root access. `ssh`, `nohup` and `screen` might be able to get me somewhere, but I'd like to drop in a list with commands, like

```
run="100-200" mkdir "$run" && cd "$run" && ./main 100 200 && ./plot
run="100-300" mkdir "$run" && cd "$run" && ./main 100 300 && ./plot
```

It would be great if I could just supply `./main 100 200 && ./plot` and it would run it into a new working directory.

Is there some scheduling software for that? I need something for Linux that is free. Bonus points if I can install it into my home directory.

---

So far, I have found TORQUE, and some people at my university apprently run a cluster with HTCondor.

Answer (score 0):

Install on your servers Sun Grid Engine (I think last free from Sun was 6.2; since Oracle bought it there were some problems to download newer version. However, the old one is more than enough for the ~100 nodes that we use.). This is  a proper queueing system. It will take care of scheduling for you. Believe me this work that will pay back.

Comment: I just checked it. Oracle let the SGE go. You can find it on http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/

Comment: SGE does a really good job, but IMHO you cannot install it as non-root. It creates dedicated users, needs an execution daemon and so on...

Comment: actually it's even better to not install sge with root account. i use on both cluster that I have sgeadmin. the deamon - there you are probably right.